# Upload image using ajax and form submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to upload an image to the server using Ajax, but there is a problem. Would somebody please help me what is wrong here. I could submit the image using submit form but not ajax.
here is my code:

html:

```
<div id="uploadPic" onclick="getFile()">
Select a photo to upload
</div>
<form name="myForm" id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<div style='height: 0px;width:0px; overflow:hidden;'>
<input id="upfile" class="botpic" type="file" name="avatar" value="upload" required="" onchange="sub1()">
</div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function getFile(){
   document.getElementById("upfile").click();
}
function sub1(){
var photo = document.getElementById("upfile");
    var file = photo.files[0];
    data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    data: data
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,  // do not process the data as url encoded params
    contentType: false,   // by default jQuery sets this to urlencoded string
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( output ) {
       document.getElementById('picTmp').innerHTML = output;;
    }
});
}
```

PHP code:

```
if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
$fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
$kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileExt = end($kaboom);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
 .......
}
```

Comment: Are you getting server-side or client-side errors?

Comment: It seems the it send the data to the server, but it cannot get into the if (isset..). I tested the php code without ajax buy regular submitting the form. everything works fine. The image updates properly, but the page needs to be refreshed to show the updated image. So, I am going to use ajax, but cannot do that at all.

Comment: use var_dump function to inspect request variables.
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES); and things get clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found where the problem is. Maybe it is useful for others struggling with **ajax** uploading a file.Now it is working perfectly. 
The solution is:

In the **php** code, all the `["avatar"]` should be replaced with `["file"]` as we are sending the file specified as `file` in **ajax**.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you're missing a comma after the data parameter declaration. That might be your only issue.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    data: data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    //etc...
```

Comment: There is comma after data parameter in the actual code, but during copy/paste it missed here. So this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What's the name of your PHP script? That's what you should specify as 'url':

```
url: 'script_name.php',
```

Comment: I noticed that. There is a php file name in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin could help you

[Jquery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

I had a lot of problem making from myself and with this plugin everething works, just try, this

```
$('form').ajaxForm(function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that without using `preventDefault()` method in your script, 
you submit the form to the same page using `action=""` and `method="post"`, thus never entering your `$.ajax()`;

I've done something like this

```
$('#query_projects').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);            

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'query_tab_projets.php',
        mimeType:'application/json',
        dataType:'json',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){                            
            alert(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
        },
        error: function(msg){
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg,null,4));
        }
    });             
});
```

where `#query_projects` is my form id

Comment: I checked, it entered into the php file but cannot go through the if statement. It seems the ajax cannot capture the file name.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. I use echo, print_r(php) and alert(JS) to monitor the data and see what goes through. Don't know if you use those, but it helps me greatly for debugging