# how to send an image from one file to another file in php with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, file

I have a page on which registered customers can upload their image; I provide a file input field and text field for that particular image description. When the customer has uploaded the file, I show a preview of the uploaded image and data. After that, when user clicks on the submit button, I call a php script through ajax and get the text field value but how can i get the image as well?

This is my file input code:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_image" id="upload_image" onchange="readURL(this);" >
```

This is my ajax code that calls a php script:

```
function generatePdf()
{
   $.ajax({
    url:      "pdfcert.php",
    type:     "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      name:   $('#tag').val(),
      title:  $('#title').val(),
      body:   $('#cert_text').html(),
      issued: document.getElementById("sel1").value
    }
   }).done(function(data){
     alert(JSON.stringify(data));
   });
}
```

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068701/upload-image-using-ajax-and-form-submitting). Might be it will help you to submit file with ajax.

Comment: So when do you pass the image in your code? You say you show a preview, that means you have the image data somewhere, right?

Comment: Ya, i have image data.